# How can I draw a road with more than 2 locations with OSM Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, openstreetmap

I want to draw a road that is a road type car with the Flutter OSM Plugin package. I'm trying to draw road with more than 2 locations but it's not working for ios.

```
await mapController.drawRoad(
     GeoPoint(
       latitude: 41.006583, 
       longitude: 28.673005,
      ),
     GeoPoint(
       latitude: 40.997773, 
       longitude: 28.873506,
      ),
     roadType: RoadType.car,
     roadOption: RoadOption(
       roadColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 78, 33),
       roadWidth: 5,
       showMarkerOfPOI: true,
      ),
     intersectPoint: [
      GeoPoint(
        latitude: 41.058638,
        longitude: 28.706307,
       ),
      GeoPoint(
        latitude: 41.061744,
        longitude: 28.812394,
       ),
     ],
);
```